# Delay grid reload in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, delay

When I delete a product from the store, my grid updates before the product is actually deleted. This causes my product to still appear in the grid after it is deleted. How can I fix this?

```
deleteProduct: function (a, b, c, d, e, responseObject) {
    var id = responseObject.data.ProductID;
    var gridStore = Ext.getCmp('prodDetailsGrid').getStore();

    Ext.Msg.confirm("Confirmation", "Do you want to permanently delete this product?", function (btnText) {
        if (btnText === "yes") {
            Direct.Product.DeleteProduct(id);
            Ext.toast('Product Deleted');
            var gridStore = Ext.getCmp('prodDetailsGrid').getStore();
            gridStore.load().delay(500);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening over here and what is causing issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the load after the request completes:

```
deleteProduct: function (a, b, c, d, e, responseObject) {
    var id = responseObject.data.ProductID;
    var gridStore = Ext.getCmp('prodDetailsGrid').getStore();

    Ext.Msg.confirm("Confirmation", "Do you want to permanently delete this product?", function (btnText) {
        if (btnText === "yes") {
            var gridStore = Ext.getCmp('prodDetailsGrid').getStore();
            Direct.Product.DeleteProduct(id, () => gridStore.load());
            Ext.toast('Product Deleted');
            gridStore.load();
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to perform delete operation first and only after delete response is received you want to reload the store.

This can be achieved using callback. You can pass another parameter to **Direct.Product.DeleteProduct** as function and can execute passed function after processing is finished.

```
DeleteProduct: function(id, callback) {
    // predefined code
    if(callback) {
      callback();
    } 
}
```

Otherwise you can also use **Promise**

```
Promise.resolve(Direct.Product.DeleteProduct(id)).then(function(response) 
{
   //Load the store
}, function(error) {
   //handle error case
})
```

In case if your DeleteProduct method uses Ext.Ajax call, you can always invoke callback in success method of Ext.Ajax.request.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own problem. he only thing I changed with the code was adding the gridStore var before my backend controller call. I am not sure why this made it work... but I will not complain.

```
deleteProduct: function (a, b, c, d, e, responseObject) {
    var id = responseObject.data.ProductID;
    var gridStore = Ext.getCmp('prodDetailsGrid').getStore();

    Ext.Msg.confirm("Confirmation", "Do you want to permanently delete this product?", function (btnText) {
        if (btnText === "yes") {
            var gridStore = Ext.getCmp('prodDetailsGrid').getStore();
            Direct.Product.DeleteProduct(id);
            Ext.toast('Product Deleted');
            gridStore.load();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This won't make any difference. You need to wait until the request completes before calling the load.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't but for some reason it did. It seemed to delay the one call enough to return after the backend controller call finished.